# crashes on button press

Tags: android, sms, android-context

I'm trying to build a simple app that draws unread SMS count from the sms folder and display it on screen, after snooping around here I found the following codes to be useful(modified)

```
public class SMSReceiver {

    public SMSReceiver() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public String getSMS(Context context){
        String s = querySMS(context);
        return s;
    }

    private static String querySMS(Context context){

        final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
        int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();

        String s = Integer.toString(unreadMessagesCount); //convert to string

        return s;
    }
}
```

and this is the codes I have in the main

```
    public void retrieveSMS(){
        SMSReceiver s = new SMSReceiver();
        SMS=s.getSMS(this);
        TextView SMSView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SMSCount);
        SMSView.setText(SMS);
    }
}
```

These are my layout , nothing fancy

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:onClick="retrieveSMS"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SMSCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="0"  />
```

It crashes when I'm trying to press the button to retrieve the SMS count number, I have no idea how to diagnose the logcat. But I suspect is context problem.

Comment: post the logcat please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onClick method should have a View parameter.
Try:

```
public void retrieveSMS(View view){
    SMSReceiver s = new SMSReceiver();
    SMS=s.getSMS(this);
    TextView SMSView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SMSCount);
    SMSView.setText(SMS);
}
```

Comment: It is the signature that the onClick methods should have. They must be public, return void and have a View parameter.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer to use OnClickListener instead of a "magic string" in the XML.